# Entering strings into a 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, character-arrays

For one part of a homework assignment, the user is prompted to enter words that will be stored in a 2D array. These entered strings will then be hidden in a word search puzzle. The prompt needs to keep looping until the user enters the word 'done' or the user has entered 20 words. Also if the word is bigger than the actual puzzle, an error message should print and the prompt will loop again. I thought a while loop was the best way to approach this problem.

This is what I have so far:

```
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
char word[20][100] = {};
int i = 0;

while(i < 20)
    {
      printf("Enter a word you would like hidden in the puzzle. Type 'done' when finished:\n");
      scanf("%s",word[i]);
      if((strlen(word[i]) > row) || (strlen(word[i]) > column))
      {
        printf("Error. Word was too long to enter into puzzle.\n");
      }
      else
      {
        i++;
      }
    }
```

The loop continues until 20 words have been entered, but how do I reconfigure the while statement so the program exits the loop after the word 'done' is entered? Also, when 'done' is entered, it should not be entered into the array. The last string in the array should be what was entered just before 'done'.

Comment: Have you heard of [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)? Or the [`break`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/break) statement?

Answer (score 2):

```
   while(i < 20)
   {
      printf("Enter a word you would like hidden in the puzzle. Type 'done' when finished:\n");
      scanf("%s",word[i]);

      if(strcmp(word[i],"done")==0)
          break;


      if((strlen(word[i]) > row) || (strlen(word[i]) > column))
      {
          printf("Error. Word was too long to enter into puzzle.\n");
      }
      else
      {
         i++;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code:

```
...
scanf("%s",word[i]);
if(strcmp(word[i],"done")==0){
    strcpy(word[i],"");
    break;
}
if((strlen(word[i]) > row) || (strlen(word[i]) > column))
...
```

Hope it helped...

Comment: Yes that exits the loop when I input 'done' but that command also inputs 'done' into the array when that shouldn't be one of the words that will be hidden in the final puzzle. Is there a different way to tweak it so that doesn't happen?